# (SSRS) IIF Statement - Blank Data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, designer

I'm not sure why but my IIF Statement doesn't seem to want to work.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value),Fields!Calculated_Dummy.Value, Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)
```

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH2nP.png)

There is data available.

Comment: Whats the error? Did you try to run first `IsNothing(..)`  whats the o/p of this function

Comment: I'm not getting any error at all.

Comment: It purely won't display data.

Comment: Probably Fields!Calculated_Address.Value is empty string. Try =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value) OR Fields!Calculated_Address.Value="",Fields!Calculated_Dummy.Value, Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)

Comment: It is still blank. The field ``` Fields!Calculated_Address.Value``` is not empty.

Comment: Check my answer. I have also added Trim to remove spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your expression with the following

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value) OR Trim(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)="",Fields!Calculated_Dummy.Value, Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)
```

**Sampled dataset**

```
select 'address1' as address, 'address has value' as dummy
UNION ALL
select '' as address, 'address is empty string' as dummy
UNION ALL
select null as address, 'address is null' as dummy
UNION ALL
select '   ' as address, 'address contains spaces' as dummy
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Then please provide as a query with sample data like these in my answer (I have updated it)

Answer (score 0):

My query is created through a program but here it is in simple terms.

```
/*
 * Disclaimer!!!
 * This is not a real query being executed, but a simplified version for general vision.
 * Executing it with any other tool may produce a different result.
 */
 
select 
    [Customer].[CustID] as [Customer_CustID],
    [OrderRel].[OrderNum] as [OrderRel_OrderNum],
    [OrderRel].[PartNum] as [OrderRel_PartNum],
    [OrderDtl].[LineDesc] as [OrderDtl_LineDesc],
    [OrderRel].[LoadNum_c] as [OrderRel_LoadNum_c],
    [OrderRel].[DropSeq_c] as [OrderRel_DropSeq_c],
    [OrderHed].[PONum] as [OrderHed_PONum],
    [JobProd].[JobNum] as [JobProd_JobNum],
    [SerialNo].[SerialNumber] as [SerialNo_SerialNumber],
    [OrderDtl].[ShipComment] as [OrderDtl_ShipComment],
    [OrderRel].[OrderLine] as [OrderRel_OrderLine],
    [OrderRel].[OrderRelNum] as [OrderRel_OrderRelNum],
    [OrderRel].[SellingReqQty] as [OrderRel_SellingReqQty],
    [OrderRel].[ShipToNum] as [OrderRel_ShipToNum],
    [Customer].[Name] as [Customer_Name],
    [Customer].[Address1] as [Customer_Address1],
    [Customer].[Address2] as [Customer_Address2],
    [Customer].[Address3] as [Customer_Address3],
    [Customer].[City] as [Customer_City],
    [Customer].[State] as [Customer_State],
    [Customer].[Country] as [Customer_Country],
    [Customer].[PhoneNum] as [Customer_PhoneNum],
    [UD100].[LoadName_c] as [UD100_LoadName_c],
    [UD100].[LoadingMeters_c] as [UD100_LoadingMeters_c],
    [UD100].[TrailerType_c] as [UD100_TrailerType_c],
    [UD100].[Carrier_c] as [UD100_Carrier_c],
    [UD100].[Key1] as [UD100_Key1],
    (CONCAT(ShipTo.Name,'  ',
            ShipTo.Address1,'  ',
            ShipTo.City,'  ',
            ShipTo.State,'  ',
            ShipTo.Zip,'  ',
            ShipTo.Country) + Dummy) as [Calculated_Address],
    (COALESCE(CONVERT(nvarchar, UD100.DateCustContact_c, 105), CONVERT(nvarchar, UD100.CollectionDate_c, 105), CONVERT(nvarchar, UD100.AvailableDate_c, 105), (CASE 
 --Jan
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1) then 'Early January' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,14) then 'Mid January'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,27) then 'Late January' 
 --Feb  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),2,1) then 'Early Feburary' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),2,14) then 'Mid Feburary'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),2,27) then 'Late Feburary' 
   
 --Mar  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),3,1) then 'Early March' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),3,14) then 'Mid March'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),3,27) then 'Late March' 
 --Apr  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),4,1) then 'Early April' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),4,14) then 'Mid April'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),4,27) then 'Late April' 
 --May  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),5,1) then 'Early May' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),5,14) then 'Mid May'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),5,27) then 'Late May' 
 --Jun  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),6,1) then 'Early June' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),6,14) then 'Mid June'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),6,27) then 'Late June' 
 --Jul  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),7,1) then 'Early July' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),7,14) then 'Mid July'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),7,27) then 'Late July' 
 --Aug  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),8,1) then 'Early August' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),8,14) then 'Mid August'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),8,27) then 'Late August' 
 --Sept  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),9,1) then 'Early September' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),9,14) then 'Mid September'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),9,27) then 'Late September' 
 --Oct  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),10,1) then 'Early October' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),10,14) then 'Mid October'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),10,27) then 'Late October'   
 --Nov  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),11,1) then 'Early November' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),11,14) then 'Mid November'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),11,27) then 'Late November' 
 --Dec  
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),12,1) then 'Early December' 
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),12,14) then 'Mid December'   
   WHEN UD100.Date01 = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),12,27) then 'Late December'   
   else 
   'No date' 
 end))) as [Calculated_PlannedDate],
    [UD100].[LoadDesc_c] as [UD100_LoadDesc_c],
    [ShipTo].[Name] as [ShipTo_Name],
    [ShipTo].[Address1] as [ShipTo_Address1],
    [ShipTo].[Address2] as [ShipTo_Address2],
    [ShipTo].[Address3] as [ShipTo_Address3],
    [ShipTo].[City] as [ShipTo_City],
    [ShipTo].[State] as [ShipTo_State],
    [ShipTo].[ZIP] as [ShipTo_ZIP],
    [ShipTo].[Country] as [ShipTo_Country],
    [OrderDtl].[OrderNum] as [OrderDtl_OrderNum],
    [OrderDtl].[OrderLine] as [OrderDtl_OrderLine],
    [OrderHed].[OrderNum] as [OrderHed_OrderNum],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy_2]
from Erp.OrderHed as OrderHed
inner join Erp.OrderDtl as OrderDtl on 
    OrderHed.Company = OrderDtl.Company
    and OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
    and ( not OrderDtl.PartNum like 'CONTRACT%'  )

inner join Erp.OrderRel as OrderRel on 
    OrderDtl.Company = OrderRel.Company
    and OrderDtl.OrderNum = OrderRel.OrderNum
    and OrderDtl.OrderLine = OrderRel.OrderLine
    and ( OrderRel.OpenRelease = 1  or OrderRel.OpenRelease = 0  )

left outer join Erp.JobProd as JobProd on 
    OrderRel.Company = JobProd.Company
    and OrderRel.OrderNum = JobProd.OrderNum
    and OrderRel.OrderLine = JobProd.OrderLine
    and OrderRel.OrderRelNum = JobProd.OrderRelNum
left outer join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    JobProd.Company = JobHead.Company
    and JobProd.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum
left outer join Erp.SerialNo as SerialNo on 
    JobHead.Company = SerialNo.Company
    and JobHead.JobNum = SerialNo.JobNum
inner join Ice.UD100 as UD100 on 
    OrderRel.Company = UD100.Company
    and OrderRel.LoadNum_c = UD100.Key1
    and ( UD100.Key1 = @LoadNum  )

inner join Erp.ShipTo as ShipTo on 
    OrderRel.Company = ShipTo.Company
    and OrderRel.ShipToCustNum = ShipTo.CustNum
    and OrderRel.ShipToNum = ShipTo.ShipToNum
inner join Erp.Customer as Customer on 
    OrderHed.Company = Customer.Company
    and OrderHed.CustNum = Customer.CustNum
union
select 
    [Customer_Msc].[CustID] as [Customer_Msc_CustID],
    [MscShpDt].[PackNum] as [MscShpDt_PackNum],
    [MscShpDt].[PartNum] as [MscShpDt_PartNum],
    [MscShpDt].[LineDesc] as [MscShpDt_LineDesc],
    [MscShpHd].[LoadNum_c] as [MscShpHd_LoadNum_c],
    [MscShpHd].[DropSeq_c] as [MscShpHd_DropSeq_c],
    (convert(nvarchar(15), MscShpHd.PONum)) as [Calculated_PONum],
    [JobHead_Msc].[JobNum] as [JobHead_Msc_JobNum],
    [SerialNo_Msc].[SerialNumber] as [SerialNo_Msc_SerialNumber],
    [MscShpHd].[ShipComment] as [MscShpHd_ShipComment],
    [MscShpDt].[PackLine] as [MscShpDt_PackLine],
    (0) as [Calculated_MiscLine],
    [MscShpDt].[Quantity] as [MscShpDt_Quantity],
    [MscShpDt].[ShipToNum] as [MscShpDt_ShipToNum],
    [MscShpHd].[Name] as [MscShpHd_Name],
    [MscShpHd].[Address1] as [MscShpHd_Address1],
    [MscShpHd].[Address2] as [MscShpHd_Address2],
    [MscShpHd].[Address3] as [MscShpHd_Address3],
    [MscShpHd].[City] as [MscShpHd_City],
    [MscShpHd].[State] as [MscShpHd_State],
    [MscShpHd].[Country] as [MscShpHd_Country],
    [Customer_Msc].[PhoneNum] as [Customer_Msc_PhoneNum],
    [UD100_Msc].[LoadName_c] as [UD100_Msc_LoadName_c],
    [UD100_Msc].[LoadingMeters_c] as [UD100_Msc_LoadingMeters_c],
    [UD100_Msc].[TrailerType_c] as [UD100_Msc_TrailerType_c],
    [UD100_Msc].[Carrier_c] as [UD100_Msc_Carrier_c],
    [UD100_Msc].[Key1] as [UD100_Msc_Key1],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummyfield],
    ('') as [Calculated_DummyField2],
    [UD100_Msc].[LoadDesc_c] as [UD100_Msc_LoadDesc_c],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy3],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy4],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy5],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy6],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy7],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy8],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy9],
    ('') as [Calculated_Dummy10],
    (0) as [Calculated_Dummy11],
    (0) as [Calculated_Dummy12],
    (0) as [Calculated_Dummy13],
    (CONCAT(MscShpHd.Name,'  ',
            MscShpHd.Address1,'  ',
            MscShpHd.City,'  ',
            MscShpHd.State,'  ',
            MscShpHd.Zip,'  ',
            MscShpHd.Country)) as [Calculated_MiscAddress],
    ((CASE 
   WHEN MscShpDt.PackNum LIKE '0%'THEN 'MISC' 
   WHEN MscShpDt.PackNum LIKE '1%'THEN 'MISC' 
   WHEN MscShpDt.PackNum LIKE '2%'THEN 'MISC' 
   ELSE 'N/A' 
  END)) as [Calculated_Misc_Order]
from Erp.MscShpHd as MscShpHd
inner join Erp.MscShpDt as MscShpDt on 
    MscShpHd.Company = MscShpDt.Company
    and MscShpHd.PackNum = MscShpDt.PackNum
left outer join Erp.JobHead as JobHead_Msc on 
    MscShpDt.Company = JobHead_Msc.Company
    and MscShpDt.JobNum = JobHead_Msc.JobNum
left outer join Erp.SerialNo as SerialNo_Msc on 
    JobHead_Msc.Company = SerialNo_Msc.Company
    and JobHead_Msc.JobNum = SerialNo_Msc.JobNum
inner join Erp.Customer as Customer_Msc on 
    Customer_Msc.Company = MscShpHd.Company
    and Customer_Msc.CustNum = MscShpHd.CustNum
inner join Ice.UD100 as UD100_Msc on 
    UD100_Msc.Key1 = MscShpHd.LoadNum_c
    and UD100_Msc.Company = MscShpHd.Company
    and ( UD100_Msc.Key1 = @LoadNum  )

where (MscShpHd.ShipDate >= dateadd (year, -2, Constants.Today))
order by OrderRel.OrderNum Desc
```

[Data Returned from Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDoYL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apologise to everyone.

I missed `Calculated_Dummy` out of my Query in the RDL file.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value) OR Trim(Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)="",Fields!Calculated_Dummy.Value, Fields!Calculated_Address.Value)
```

Worked perfectly. Thank you :)